# SQL запрос: есть одна таблица, требуется вывести все записи, в которых значение определенного столбца встречается только 1 раз

Tags: sql

SQL запрос: есть одна таблица, требуется вывести все записи, в которых значение определенного столбца встречается только 1 раз

Comment: В общем виде `select * from table group by столбец having count(1)=1` но на многих SQL прямо так не заработает и нужно искать другие пути зависящие от диалекта (который вы не указали)

Answer (score 2):

например

```
SELECT count(id) num,id FROM t1 group by id having count(id) = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b55/2